# Selenium does not identify element on second test

Tags: java, selenium, testng, element

Its happening with every testscript I try to create with selenium + TestNG. **After 1st @test method webdriver never identifies elements on rest `@test` methods and always declare them as fail.**

To make it simple following is the scenario:
The web driver loads up a page and in 1st `@test(priority=0)` it searches for google sign-in button and clicks it to load google sign in screen.
In 2nd `@test(priority=1)` i m trying to identify the email textfield by its ID but i always get an exception of element not found.
But if i move the code from 2nd test to 1st test it executes successfully

Here is a piece of code. The `enterCredentials()` method is where the problem occurs.

```
public class CSgoogleLogin extends CloudDriver {

@Test(priority=0)
public void attemptLogin(){

    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 100))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ROOT-2521314']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/center/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/img")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ROOT-2521314']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/center/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/img")).click();     
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void enterCredentials(){
    WebElement myDynamicElement;
    if(!driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).isDisplayed()){
     myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 1))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Email")));
    }
    //Entering Username
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

    myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 1))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']")));
    //Entering Password
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
}}
```

The following is the CloudDriver Class. More importantly while running on debug the code perform correctly.

```
public class CloudDriver {

protected WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUP(){

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://apps3.thecloudstream.com/");
}

@AfterSuite
public void Closing(){

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait time until elements are loaded? This might be happening because the second test doesn't know the state of the page which is changed by the first test's click and tries to perform the operations you have mentioned in it.

Comment: Actually the page loads even in no time with Email and next button there. But the second test keeps waiting for email field and then declares it as not found.
But if i perform the action of 2nd test within the method of first test. All the elements are found filled and successfully signs in

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the code for "CloudDriver" class ?

I don't see any failures looking at the current code. Can you try setting the driver instance in @BeforeClass method ? Something like below :

```
public class CSgoogleLogin extends CloudDriver {
Webdriver driver = null;
@BeforeClass
public void setUp(){
driver = getDriverInstance();//Get this instance from the super class.
} 
@Test(priority=0)
public void attemptLogin(){}
@Test(priority=1)
public void enterCredentials(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by applying implicit wait.
i.e in enter credentials

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.seconds);
    // Entering Username
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys(
            "daisy.d.bogus@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='next']")).click();
```

Implicit wait polls the dom for given time until element or elements in question are not found.